# Angular - Where to place script calls for firebase

Tags: angular, firebase

I am writing an angular app and syncing it with google's firebase. During the process, it asks me to place the following code in the body.

```
<!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first -->
<script src="/__/firebase/7.14.3/firebase-app.js"></script>

<!-- TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
     https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries -->

<!-- Initialize Firebase -->
<script src="/__/firebase/init.js"></script>
```

I am not sure where to place this in the angular app. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install firebase using `npm` instead in an angular app:

> Install the firebase npm package and save it to your package.json file by running:

```
npm install --save firebase
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#node.js-apps

Comment: I did that and was confused as to why the instructions wanted me to add additional files.

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#add-sdks-initialize there are 4 sections in this step, since angular is installed using npm, then all u need to do is install firebase using npm, and add the firebase config object